# Android: ActivityGroup -- How to "pop" a view

Tags: android, tabactivity, activitygroup

I have implemented a ActivityGroup in my TabView.

I can successfully add a view to the ActivityGroup from an activity in a tab.

How do I pop this new view off the stack to go back to the original view??

In the ActivityGroup I handle the BackButton with a Finsih() but the entire app goes away and the home screen is displayed. Note that the app is not killed, it's still running.

(Written in .NET)

```
public override void OnBackPressed ()
    {
        int length = mIdList.Count;
        if (length > 1)
        {
            Activity current = LocalActivityManager.GetActivity (mIdList [length - 1]);
            current.Finish();
        }           
        base.OnBackPressed ();
    }
```

(I'm coming from an iOS background)

Comment: more likely to get good answer if you post your code. But generally View parents have some .remove() methods that will remove the children views given various parameters.

Comment: [ActivityGroup](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityGroup.html) is deprecated. You You should look into using `Fragments`.

Comment: When you say "pop this new view off the stack to go back to the original view" do you mean `Activity` instead of `View` if not this question doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 0):

First, I agree with aneal that you should try [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) rather than activity groups. If you do, the following text from the Android [on-line training class](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html) appears to address the issue:

> Keep in mind that when you perform fragment transactions, such as replace or remove one, it's often appropriate to allow the user to navigate backward and "undo" the change. To allow the user to navigate backward through the fragment transactions, you must call addToBackStack() before you commit the FragmentTransaction.

When you add the view, call addToBackStack() before committing your "add fragment" transaction.